# Why do I get -1 from this statement?

Tags: java, modulo

```
    if(heading == 2){
        nextY = (y-1) % 20;
        nextX = x;
    }
```

When debugging this program, my heading is 2 and y = 0, however, when I come to this if statement, nextY becomes -1. Why is it not cycling properly? (0-19)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how mod operation generally works for negative numbers in programming (in all languages I tried it in).
But you can easily make number positive before doing mod

```
nextY = (y + 20 - 1) % 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Modulo operators often return negative numbers for negative inputs. For example, C# will give you a number from `-356..359` for the expression `x % 360`.

Instead of subtracting 1 then taking modulo 20, you can add 19, which is the same thing but keeps the number positive, or you can use the ternary operator:

```
nextY = (y+19) % 20; // or
nextY = (nextY == 0) ? 19 : nextY - 1;
```